# Count elements in simple array and order them by highest first

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array like the example below (from `var_dump($tagged);`:

```
array (size=1)
0 => 
array (size=7)
  0 => string '#raining' (length=8)
  1 => string '#raining' (length=8)
  2 => string '#driving' (length=8)
  3 => string '#hungrySoon' (length=11)
  4 => string '#strangeworld' (length=13)
  5 => string '#fruitweekFunky' (length=15)
  6 => string '#kevins_rainbow_disco' (length=21)
  7 => string '#raining' (length=8)
  8 => string '#fruitweekFunky' (length=15)
```

I am simply after displaying the array as follows (From the most frequent first):

```
  #raining
  #fruitweekFunky
  #driving ...etc
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: array_count_values but this seems to require integers

Comment: And how do you track `"most frequent first"`? Where does the array come from?

Comment: More information in the question never strays far!

Comment: I just need to list the words by the most common occurrences if this makes sense. Therefore in the example `#raining` wuld appear at the top as there are 3 instances of the word in the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve exactly what you've asked for (a descending ordered array of the highest occurences to the lowest) *step by step*:

Count the number of occurences:

```
$occurences = array_count_values($tagged[0]);
```

Sort the array (by value, because the number of occurrences is the current array *value* and the tag is the *key* - [`arsort()` maintains the original keys](http://www.php.net//manual/en/array.sorting.php)):

```
arsort($occurences);
```

Get array of the keys for output (because the tags are currently keys):

```
var_dump(array_keys($occurences));
```

Comment: when I return the array from the function I cant get it to echo the words - only the numeric count

Comment: That's what `array_keys()` is for (which the previous answer is missing). See example: http://codepad.org/k8Ik33tI

Comment: Sorry - it's 3am here and I missed the array keys on my return value. Works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: Go to sleep - late night coding leads to silly mistakes that will cost you in more time spent tomorrow!

Comment: Well, this solution lacked the `$tagged[0]` earlier (which you took from mine) ;-) Plus you don't have to sort the array as it is already sorted. Briefly, copy pasting of a solution in order to add nothing to it is not very good acting.

Comment: @Loic I'm not sure what you mean re: sorting? If you take the sort out, the results are wrong (they aren't sorted, just have duplicates taken out) - http://codepad.org/zddJUaya

Answer (score 2):

Fact is, `$tagged` is an array of arrays. So you need to take its first element.

Try :

```
$result = array_count_values(array_values($tagged[0]));

var_dump($result);
```